# foreach loop for looping through Json

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I need to print each value looping through the below json data.

```
{
    "Name": "xyz",
    "Address": "abc",
    "City": "London",
    "Phone": "123456"
}
```

What I tried is:

```
$DecodedFile = json_decode(file_get_contents("file.json"));

foreach ($DecodedFile->{$key} as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `->{$key}`. It's just:

```
foreach ($DecodedFile as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
```

or if you want to use the key as well:

```
foreach ($DecodedFile as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value <br>";
}
```

After you `json_decode`, you get this `$DecodedFile`:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'Name' => string 'xyz' (length=3)
  public 'Address' => string 'abc' (length=3)
  public 'City' => string 'London' (length=6)
  public 'Phone' => string '123456' (length=6)
```

And then it's just regular [object iteration](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php).

You *can* use that syntax if you want to get a single specific property from the decoded object, although the brackets aren't necessary.

```
$key = 'City';
echo $DecodedFile->$key;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've jumbled up your foreach a little. Change it to this:

```
foreach($DecodedFile as $key=>$value)
```